# OPTIONS request returning 403 on a presigned S3 url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, aws-sdk

I have an s3 bucket. The bucket has CORS enabled. When I access a resource via GET from the bucket via the browser with javascript the resource works and the options request is successful. When I presign a request via the AWS API I get a 403 returned on the options request for the presigned link. This happens after the initial request returns a 302 redirect. The reason this is happening is because I am redirecting to a pre-signed AWS S3 URL. This has a different domain name to the initial URL and is causing the CORS check to fail as `origin` `null` is sent by the client to the redirected url. I need the presigned url to have the same domain as the redirect. Is this possible using the PHP SDK version 3?

Comment: Why does the initial request return 302?

Comment: Because the endpoint creates a pre signed URL from S3. The location in the redirect is that signed URL. I return a 302 as I want the browser to follow that url

Comment: Did you find a solution? I had a similar issue.